# Elasticsearch match_phrase_prefix query not working with analyzer_startswith

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. When I use `match_phrase_prefix` on a single field it works, but if I use `match_phrase_prefix` on multiple fields it doesn't work.

If I search for `hybrid,121` with the query below I get results when `field3` length is greater than 4 digits. I need to get result starts with 1st digit.

My query looks like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "feild1": "p"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "feild2": {
                    "query": "HYBRID "
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "feild3": {
                    "query": "121"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10"
}
```

`field3` is long in the database. I convert `long` to `char` when I load the data.

My mappings

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_startswith": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "pty": {
      "properties": {
        "feild2": {
          "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
          "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "feild3": {
          "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
          "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case. Your mapping should be like this:

```
PUT index_name
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith", 
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "field2": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith", 
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "field3": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith", 
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample document:

```
POST index_name/type_name
{
  "field1":"hatim",
  "field2":"stovewala",
  "field3":"india"
}
```

Query should be like this:

```
GET index_name/type_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "field1": "hat"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "field2": "s"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "field3": "in"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i change mapping of feild 3 as long  , i get this error long is not accepted for analyzer

Comment: "properties": {
                "feild": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "long"
                }

Comment: Please help me,only when i do full  load (like 7 million records)i get results null, if i do partial load like (2000 records ) its working fine

Comment: remove ""search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith", "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith"". you don't need this as you are indexing a long field. This are applied on text field and not on long fields. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, In this way we can't search  number starts with .requirement is i should search on firstname,lastname and id starts with , when user enters name result should be shown with starts with , here i  get results for only number and only name ,but only the name,number is getting issue ,i get results only after 4 or 5 digits depends on name iam getting results when i do full load .                                                                Now working index has no mapping for number but i inserted number as string.to give match phrase prefix.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope that meets your requirement.

Comment: here if  feild3 is long type should  i convert  to string

Comment: Yes you need to convert it to text. Because you are searching it with starts with.

Comment: Thank you I did mapping load data after full load same issue couldn't get result , some how I made some changes in query that make my issue solved . For now iam getting results .

Comment: Which version of ES you are using?

Comment: Elasticsearch 5.3

Comment: How many documents you are indexing? Is the data correct? From where are you indexing documents to ES?

Comment: I don't think number of records would make a problem. I have indexed 60 million records and have faced no problem. There is something wrong with the data.

Comment: Ok I'll check . Now i have another issue i.e. When I search name like me & my music inc . I get result till 'me & ' after this result is null . Do you think I should change my query

Comment: I guess this is something to do with the analyzers. You will have to check how analyzers deal with special characters like &.